# mongoose update multiple documents then set new values to rest of documents from list

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm essentially trying to update all the documents in `car` collection using mongoose, first update all documents by setting `active` to `false` then update some documents from list to setting `active` to `true`.  how can I run the two queries simultaneously:

```
Car.update({"active": true}, {"$set":{"active": false}}, {"multi": true} )

Car.update({ _id: { $in: carlist } },{ $set: { active : true } })
```

Answer (score 0):

JS fires everything asynchronously. Easiest way to make sure the first statement fires first, then continuing to the next statement is adding await.

```
await Car.update({"active": true}, {"$set":{"active": false}}, {"multi": true} )
Car.update({ _id: { $in: carlist } },{ $set: { active : true } })
```

This is also assuming your function is in async